# CMS для проекта на Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cms

сделала небольшой сайт на Angular https://dianaivanovna.github.io/positive/ .
Он готов, осталось загрузить на хостинг и в работу. Но заказчику потребовалось, чтобы он мог изменять контент на сайте. Добавлять фотки в фотогалерею, изменять описание фоткам, добавлять поездки и т д.
Желательно, не разбираясь при этом в коде.

Как это можно сделать? Первая мысль - cms. Начала гуглить и разбираться в wordpress, но там придется переписывать весь код. Есть какой-нибудь другой способ?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартных решений - нет. Выхода 2:

1. Составить очень-очень подробную доку, поясняющую куда, какие и как файлы класть, чтобы на сайте появилось то, что нужно. Убедиться, что заказчик понял и осилил доку.
2. Реализовать функционал админки для сайта, согласовав с заказчиком функционал и стоимость.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно Angular и аналогичные ему технологии работают в связке с API сервисами. Но, их написание и последующая интеграция с ними вполне может оказаться гораздо более сложной и трудоёмкой задачей, чем перенос проекта с Angular на тот же WordPress.

Здесь нужно для начала собрать и проанализировать требования к функционалу, а уже потом выбирать технологический стек и согласовывать стоимость и сроки.

Не исключено, что в результате обсуждения с заказчиком, ему окажется вполне достаточно подробной инструкции о том, какие файлы и куда добавлять (но это не точно).